# Guardar alguns elementos de um array em outro array

Tags: c, array

Tenho definido um *array* de inteiro na qual será apontado por um ponteiro e depois tenho um outro *array* que irá armazenar apenas alguns números na quais são numero pares, eis o código...

```
void main(void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    //vetor de dimensao 10
    int vetor [MAX] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    //apontador para vetor
    int *ptr_vetor;
    //novo vetor
    int novo_vetor[MAX];
    //apontador para novo vetor
    int *ptr_novo_vetor;
    //escolher numero
    int escolha = 0;
    //contador
    int contador = 0;

    //ponteiro apontado ao primeiro vetor
    ptr_vetor = &vetor[0];
}
```

mostra os valores do vetor

```
printf("\n--- Vetor ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        //mostra os valores do vetor
        printf("\nvalor : %d ", vetor[i]);
    }
```

mostra os valores pares apontador ao vetor

```
printf("\n\n--- Ponteiro Vetor para Numero Pares ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        //escolha apenas numeros pares
        if (*(ptr_vetor + i) % 2 == 0) {
            //mostra os valores pares apontador ao vetor
            printf("\nNumero Par : %d ", *(ptr_vetor + i));
            //adiciona o numero par ao novo vetor
            novo_vetor[i] = *(ptr_vetor + i);
            //aqui devia receber apenas os dados do novo vetor mas
            //mostra aepnas o endereço
            ptr_novo_vetor = &novo_vetor[i];
            //usei isto para iterar os jogadores, nao deu certo
            //contador++;
        }
    }
```

mostra os valores do novo vetor

```
printf("\n\n\n--- Novo Vetor ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        //mostra os valores do novo vetor
        printf("\nvalor: %d ", novo_vetor[i]);
    }
```

mostra os valores do novo ponteiro

```
printf("\n\n--- Ponteiro Novo Vetor ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        //mostra os valores do novo ponteiro
        printf("\nNovo Vetor : %d ", *(ptr_novo_vetor+i));
    }
```

ao executar o programa

[image: Resutado]

Como mostrar os dados que foram adicionados ao novo *array*, ou seja, os números pares?

Comment: Porque você cria um ponteiro que aponta para o vetor? sendo que o vetor ja é um ponteiro. Veja, *pt é igual a pt[n];

Comment: O seu problema está aqui  `novo_vetor[i] = *(ptr_vetor + i);` crie um contador para o novo_vetor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou dar uma solução que não sei se é o que deseja. Mas o código não faz muito sentido também, então não sei se fará diferença. Provavelmente está querendo fazer outra coisa e está longe do objetivo. Estou respondendo pelo que deu para entender.

Certamente tem meios melhores de fazer isto, mas não gastei muito tempo pensando no que melhorar, porque não vejo razão para este código todo existir.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int main(void) {

    //vetor de dimensao 10
    int vetor [MAX] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    //apontador para vetor
    int *ptr_vetor;
    //novo vetor
    int novo_vetor[MAX];
    //apontador para novo vetor
    int *ptr_novo_vetor;
    //escolher numero
//    int escolha = 0;
    //contador
//    int contador = 0;

    //ponteiro apontado ao primeiro vetor
    ptr_vetor = &vetor[0];

    printf("\n--- Vetor ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        //mostra os valores do vetor
        printf("\nvalor : %d ", vetor[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n\n--- Ponteiro Vetor para Numero Pares ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        //escolha apenas numeros pares
        if (*(ptr_vetor + i) % 2 == 0) {
            //mostra os valores pares apontador ao vetor
            printf("\nNumero Par : %d ", *(ptr_vetor + i));
            //adiciona o numero par ao novo vetor
            novo_vetor[i / 2] = *(ptr_vetor + i);
        }
    }
    ptr_novo_vetor = novo_vetor;

    printf("\n\n\n--- Novo Vetor ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX / 2; i++) {
        //mostra os valores do novo vetor
        printf("\nvalor: %d ", novo_vetor[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n--- Ponteiro Novo Vetor ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX / 2; i++) {
        //mostra os valores do novo ponteiro
        printf("\nNovo Vetor : %d ", *(ptr_novo_vetor+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/q99yQd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/brhhuqhn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/FilterArray.c).

Comment: excelente solução, valeu...

Comment: fiz teste para vetor com diferente tamanho e deu certo, obrigado

Comment: estou com uma outra duvida em relação a esta mesma questão, que em vez de usar array de inteiros, se poderia usar `struct array`

Comment: Pode, só não sei se deve. Este código já tem coisas esquisitas demais, ficaria mais esquisito. Ele parece não ter objetivo algum.

Comment: não é para este código, este código apenas serviu de base para dúvida de um trabalho em que simula uma partida de futebol e no final se houver empate, iriam ao prolongamento, ou seja, esses jogadores serão adicionados num outro array campo prolongamento e e já tenho essa lista mais quando vou aceder, aparece todos os jogadores, tal como tinha na duvida anterior de array de inteiros

Comment: em relação a esta mesma questão, que em vez de usar array de inteiros, se poderia usar struct array [ver link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98227/guardar-alguns-elementos-dentro-um-struct-array-em-outro-struct-array)

Answer (score 2):

Seu vetor resultante tem o tamanho errado. Se ele tem que receber apenas os números pares, ele não pode ter o mesmo tamanho que o vetor original. Se você fizer isso, vai ter que preencher o vetor resultante com valores que indicam vazio. Melhor seria você, já sabendo o conjunto de entrada, simplesmente criar um vetor de 5 posições.

O motivo de estar pulando posições na inserção é que você está inserindo quando `i` é par e colocando na posição `i`. Desse jeito, só as posições pares serão prenchidas.

Já o `ptr_novo_vetor` está mostrando esses valores esquisitos porque você nunca fez ele apontar pra lugar nenhum.

Comment: pois é a minha duvida era mesmo isso, só que já tentei implementar  um contador e mesmo assim, não deu certo