# Guardar alguns elementos de um struct array em outro struct array

Tags: c

Tenho definido um *struct array* `struct CAMPO campo[2]` na qual será apontado por um *ponteiro* `struct CAMPO *ptr_campo` e esse *ponteiro* será apontado aos jogadores inseridos no campo, eis o código definido...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10
#define MAX_PONTOS 10

typedef struct JOGADOR JOGADOR;
typedef struct CAMPO CAMPO;

struct JOGADOR {
    int num_jogador;
    int pontos;
};

struct CAMPO {
    struct JOGADOR jogadores[MAX];
};

/*novo jogador*/
struct JOGADOR novo_jogador;
/*apontador para  novo jogador*/
struct JOGADOR *ptr_jogador;
/*Array campo jogo e campo prolonagamento*/
struct CAMPO campo[2];
/*apontador para campo jogo e campo prolonagamento */
struct CAMPO *ptr_campo;

/*Prototipos das funções*/
void criar_jogador_no_campo0(void);
void definir_vencedor_ou_empate_jogo(void);
void adicionar_jogadores_empatados_campo1(int, int);
void mostrar_jogadores_no_prolongamento(void);
...
}
```

nesta função cria o jogador e insere no campo de jogo, ou seja o `campo[0]`

```
void criar_jogador_no_campo0(void) {

    int i, j;
    //aponta para campo de jogo
    ptr_campo = &campo[0];

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        campo[0] = *(ptr_campo);
        novo_jogador.num_jogador++;
        novo_jogador.pontos = 1 + rand() % MAX_PONTOS;
        ptr_jogador = &novo_jogador;
        campo[0].jogadores[i] = *ptr_jogador;
        *(ptr_campo) = campo[0];
        printf(">> Criar jogador %d com pontos %d no campo[0]...\n",
                ptr_campo->jogadores[i].num_jogador,
                ptr_campo->jogadores[i].pontos);
        j++;
    }

    if (j == MAX) {
        definir_vencedor_ou_empate_jogo();
    }
}
```

nesta função definir jogador vencedor com maior numero de pontos ou em caso de empate irão ao campo de prologamento, ou seja o `campo[1]`

```
void definir_vencedor_ou_empate_jogo(void) {

    int j, k, m, t;
    int contador = 0;
    int max = 0;

    puts("\n Determinar o jogador vencedor ou em situação de empate\n");
    //para todos os jogadores
    for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
        //se o jogador listado tiver mais pontos marcados do que max
        if (ptr_campo->jogadores[j].pontos > max) {
            //max = pontos do jogador
            max = ptr_campo->jogadores[j].pontos;
            //contador será igual a um
            contador = 1;
            //se tiver os mesmo pontos que max
        } else if (ptr_campo->jogadores[j].pontos == max) {
            //incrementa o contador
            contador++;
        }
    }//se contador for igual a um
    if (contador == 1) {
        //para todos os jogadores
        for (k = 0; k < MAX; k++) {
            //se o jogador listado tiver mais do que max pontos
            if (ptr_campo->jogadores[k].pontos == max) {
                //o jogador iterado é o vencedor
                printf(">> Jogador %d é o VENCEDOR com %d pontos(s)\n",
                        ptr_campo->jogadores[k].num_jogador,
                        ptr_campo->jogadores[k].pontos);
            }
        }//caso contrário (contador diferente de um)
    } else {
        //iterar todos os jogadores
        for (m = 0; m < MAX; m++) {
            //se os pontos do jogador listado for igual a max
            if (ptr_campo->jogadores[m].pontos == max) {
                //o jogador iterado faz parte do prolongamento
                printf(">> Jogador %d com %d pontos(s) e vai para campo[1]\n", 
                        ptr_campo->jogadores[m].num_jogador,
                        ptr_campo->jogadores[m].pontos);
            }
        }
        puts("\n\t\t--- Lista de Jogadores para campo[1] ---");
        //iterar todos os jogadores
        for (t = 0; t < MAX; t++) {
            //se os pontos do jogador listado for igual a max
            if (ptr_campo->jogadores[t].pontos == max) {
                //o jogador iterado faz parte 
               //da lista de jogadores para prolongamento
                 adicionar_jogadores_empatados_campo1
                       (ptr_campo->jogadores[t].num_jogador, contador);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a minha duvida começa nesta função em adicionar apenas os jogadores empatadas no `campo[0]` para `campo[1]`, afim de obter o vencedor, tipo depois de empatar irão ao prolongamento, só que não sei se será necessario,adiciona-los ao novo array campo ou não sei bem o que perguntar....

```
void adicionar_jogadores_empatados_campo1(int num_jogador, int quant_jogador) {

    int j = 0;
    //aponta para campo de prolongamento
    //*(ptr_campo + 1) = &campo[1]; //-> dá erro

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (num_jogador == ptr_campo->jogadores[i].num_jogador) {
            campo[1] = *(ptr_campo + i);
            campo[1].jogadores[i] = ptr_campo->jogadores[i];
            *(ptr_campo + i) = campo[1];
            printf("\t\t\t Jogador %d com %d pontos(s) adicionado no campo[1]\n",
                    (ptr_campo + i)->jogadores[i].num_jogador,
                    (ptr_campo + i)->jogadores[i].pontos);
            j++;
        }
    }

    if (j == quant_jogador) {
        //mostra os jogadores no prolongamento
        mostrar_jogadores_no_prolongamento();
    }
}
```

nesta função irá mostrar os jogadores adicionada no `campo[1]`

```
void mostrar_jogadores_no_prolongamento(void) {
    printf("\n\n--- Ponteiro para Campo 1 ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        //mostra os valores do novo ponteiro
        printf("\nAponta para ->Jogador %d com pontos %d no campo[1]",
                (ptr_campo + i)->jogadores[i].num_jogador,
                (ptr_campo + i)->jogadores[i].pontos);
    }
}
```

função main

```
int main(void) {

    criar_jogador_no_campo0();

    return 0;
}
```

cada vez que testo o programa, mostra somente esses dados em baixo, 
nunca dá empate apesar de testar varias vezes

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta dúvida é similar a dúvida que foi resolvida ontem [ver link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97857/guardar-alguns-elementos-de-um-array-em-outro-array/97861#97861)
só que post de ontem foi usado um *array* de inteiros e nessa duvida é usado um `struct array` para armazenar jogadores em diferentes situações

Veja [funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/Nv0Kru).

Comment: @bigown, a dúvida que tinha perguntado sobre se poderia usar `struct array` para guardar elementos dentro de uma outra `struct array` e confirmaste que não se deve usar isto mas por acaso, resolvi desenvolver este exemplo para servir de base para minha duvida

Comment: Essa pergunta ficou um pouco comprida, você não acha? :)

Comment: @hugomg é verdade mas não foi minha intenção, dá próxima vez irei colocar resumidamente

Comment: não se preocupe. É só que uma ótima técnica para resolver problemas é tentar criar o menor exemplo possível que demonstre o comportamento indesejado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um primeiro problema com o seu código é que que você não está alimentando a semente do gerador de números pseudoaleatorios corretamente, dessa forma o resultado de `rand` será previsível.

Para mudar o valor da semente, use a função [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/). Uma boa semente é a hora atual:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    criar_jogador_no_campo0();

    return 0;
}
```

Adicionalmente, há confusão sobre ponteiros nas funções `adicionar_jogadores_empatados_campo1` e `mostrar_jogadores_no_prolongamento`.

Um ponteiro para o campo do prolongamento pode ser obtido da seguinte forma:

```
struct CAMPO *ptr_campo_2 = ptr_campo + 1;
```

Usando esse ponteiro você pode reescrever sua função da seguinte maneira:

```
void adicionar_jogadores_empatados_campo1(int num_jogador, int quant_jogador) {

    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (num_jogador == ptr_campo->jogadores[i].num_jogador) {
            ptr_campo_2->jogadores[i] = ptr_campo->jogadores[i];
            printf("\t\t\t Jogador %d com %d pontos(s) adicionado no campo[1]\n",
                    ptr_campo_2->jogadores[i].num_jogador,
                    ptr_campo_2->jogadores[i].pontos);
            j++;
        }
    }
    // O maior valor possível de j eh quant_jogador - 1
    if (j + 1 == quant_jogador) {
        //mostra os jogadores no prolongamento
        mostrar_jogadores_no_prolongamento();
    }
}
```

É claro que você também pode obter o ponteiro para o campo de prolongamento a partir do endereço do campo do jogo com a expressão `(ptr_campo + 1)`, dessa forma, você poderia reescrever a sua função `mostrar_jogadores_no_prolongamento` assim:

```
void mostrar_jogadores_no_prolongamento(void) {
    printf("\n\n--- Ponteiro para Campo 1 ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        //mostra os valores do novo ponteiro
        printf("\nAponta para ->Jogador %d com pontos %d no campo[1]",
                (ptr_campo + 1)->jogadores[i].num_jogador,
                (ptr_campo + 1)->jogadores[i].pontos);
    }
}
```

Mas se você já tem um ponteiro para o campo de prolongamento não há motivo para repetir a aritmética de ponteiros. Apenas use o ponteiro original:

```
printf("\nAponta para ->Jogador %d com pontos %d no campo[1]",
         ptr_campo_2->jogadores[i].num_jogador,
         ptr_campo_2->jogadores[i].pontos);
```

Comment: obrigado pela orientação, por acaso, eu estava a fazer confusão nos ponteiros mas resolveu a minha duvida